# Unable to connect to localhost with mysql utilities

Tags: mysql, logins

I installed mysql utilities on my ubuntu server today, so I could use mysqldbcompare, but I just cannot connect to the mysql server with it (localhost). I created an entry into the .mylogin.cnf, using mysql_config_editor, as mentionned into the mysql utilities 1.6 documentation, and printed / tested it (with mysql), and it's ok. But if I try to run any mysql utilities command, it always fail with

```
ERROR: Access denied for user '****'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

(I put the stars myself instead of my user name).

I spent more than 2 hours searching the web, I have absolutely no clue of what's wrong... any idea ?

EDIT :
alright, let's do this step by step
First, my versions. Everything is on the same virtual machine : mysql server and client, and mysql utils.
My versions are :
MySQL server : Ver 14 Distrib 5.7.22
MySQL client : Ver 14 Distrib 5.7.22
MySQL utils : 1.6.1

- First, using phpMyAdmin (which connects correctly to mysql), I create a user named userTest, with host % and password "bonjour!".
- Then, I go to my host terminal, and type the following :
  `mysql_config_editor set --login-path=test --host=localhost --user=userTest --port=3306 --password`
- When asked, I enter the password "bonjour!"
- Then, I try to connect to mysql using the login path (no user is named "test" on the database :
  `mysql --login-path=test`
- This connects me to mysql correctly :

  `Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.`

  `Your MySQL connection id is 17`

  `Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (Ubuntu)`

  `Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.`

  `Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
  owners.`

  `Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.`

  `mysql>`
- Now I exit mysql and type a simple mysql utils command :
  `mysqlserverinfo --server=test`
- And I get 
  `ERROR: Access denied for user 'userTest'@'localhost' using password: YES`

Comment: Are you login as root user?. Either user has no  privileges or wrong password.

Comment: No, its a user I gave the needed privileges to do this. The password is correct, because if I type "mysql --login-path=exportImport", I can connect correctly. Moreover, it does not work with any of the mysql utilities command, even mysqlserverinfo.
Also, I know the command can read the .mylogin.cnf, because the error I get gives the name of the user, and not the name of the login-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so my suspicions were correct.
The python scripts of mysql utilies use the default "my_print_defaults" utility to get the credentials from a login path.
But the my_print_defaults call returns the password as a bunch of stars, unless you call it with -s...
So I modified the python script mysql/utilities/common/my_print_defaults.py to call the my_print_defaults executable with -s to get the password too. And now it works.

Comment: If you use latest version of mysql utilities (1.6.1-2), here are the modifications to do :
sudo `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/utilities/common/my_print_defaults.py`.
In method `_read_group_data(self, group)`, modify the calls to  `subprocess.call` just under the comment saying `# Group not found; use my_print_defaults to get group data` by adding "-s" as an argument before the group :
`subprocess.call([self._tool_path, "-s", group], stdout=outfile...`

Answer (score 0):

If you can access mysql shell, run the following commands

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET host = '%' WHERE host = 'localhost';
Flush privileges;
```

Then try logging into your utilities

Comment: I have access to mysql, and the server is on the same host than the mysql client I use and the mysql utils I installed. My own personal user I use to administrate is set to localhost too and I can connect correctly. I'll update the question to be more precise